# WCF web service is too busy

Tags: c#, wcf, service, web

I have a problem with busy wcf service through which clients can connect to and consume it.
Below is the error and stack trace on the server configuration and attributes of the class.

Error message and stacktrace:

```
The HTTP service located at https://my.web.service.com/Service/Service.svc is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.ExST: 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Web server configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Server.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="ServerEdi.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IWebService" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="nowa" name="ServiceWeb.WebService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IWebService"
          contract="ServiceWeb.IWebService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="nowa">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="xxxyyyzzz.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceWeb.MyCustomUserNamePasswordValidator,ServiceWeb"/>
            <windowsAuthentication includeWindowsGroups="false" allowAnonymousLogons="false"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" />

        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Class attributes:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
   //[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
  //  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
   //              ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class WebService : IWebService {}
```

If anyone could help I would be grateful for the cases described on stackoverflow not fully fit and solve my case. At the moment the service is using about 50 customers. The problem comes when I call a method that returns something and you can not call it asynchronously, because the answer must be immediately delivered.

Comment: When you say "The problem comes when I call a method that returns something and you can not call it asynchronously, because the answer must be immediately delivered." it will take as long as it takes and making it synchronous will not make it return any quicker?

Comment: I know, client will wait for answer which is object with information for him what to do next.

Comment: I can suggest you also consider thread pool settings.. (see answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835595/does-wcf-use-the-threadpool-to-bring-up-new-instances-for-a-percall-service)

Comment: Phil_P - Thread pool settings seem to be fine but if you have any suspects I can provide thread pool configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF has some default throttling values, so you are probably hitting these, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx

Normally you get this error when the client does not close the connection, the connections are open until they timeout, blocking any new calls.

Comment: Can this be caused if they are not using the "using" statement around their code when making a call?

Comment: I don't think so, in my code I tried option with try catch with close() in try and abort() call in catch. It doesn't solve problem.

Comment: Shiraz Bhaiji - so I can remove my throttling settings because default are fine.

Comment: @shiraz: so if my client code is not closing the WCF service connection, this can occur?